# D3.js: How do you tilt/rotate individual text elements within a collection without rotating them all?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

How do you tilt/rotate individual text elements within a collection without rotating them all? The js fiddle below shows the text tilted, but not individually, all in a group. I would like the text to align vertically.

http://jsfiddle.net/mcroteau/6c3puj8s/16/

```
var texts = circle.enter().append("text")
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", function(d, index){
            index = index + 1
            var y = starting
            if(index > 1){
                y = index * increment - 10
            }
            return y
        })
        .text( function (d) { 
            return "test"
         })
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "11px")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(345, 30, 0)")
```

This rotates the entire group by 45 degrees instead of each individual text element. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: Rotate result using rotate(345, 30, 0)]

As you see from the image, there is a vertical line where I would like to align the text, however each tilted. The rotate transformation is applying to all texts as if it were one element.

Comment: use the rotate attribute e.g. rotate="10 20 40" etc

Comment: Thank you. I tried, see above. Am I approaching it wrong? I see you have three values.

Comment: 3 values means 3 characters. Adjust as you see fit.

Comment: use a function `.attr("transform", (d,i) => 'rotate(${i*5})')` (use template string back quotes)

Comment: Thank you for the three values, that got me closer. Still applying to the group instead of the individual element.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue here is that translation (x and y attributes) happen before rotation -- your all text items have same pivot point of 0;0, and thus it appears as if they are rotated in group together. If you instead rotated first, the pivot point would stick to start of each text element, even if you move it afterwards with the translate.

One way to solve it, is to drop x and y attributes entirely, and use the transform attribute only. This way you can specify the order of operations and get desired result.

```
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var dataSet = [10, 20, 30, 40, 20, 10, 30];

var text = svg.selectAll('text')
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .text( function (d) { 
      return "test";
    })
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "21px")
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("class", "sequence-node-label")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i){
        var y = (i + 1) * 20;
        return "translate(0,"+y+"),rotate(345)";
    });
```

Notice, that opperations happen from right to left, which stems from transformations being traditionally represented as matrixes.